# Has PRDD (partial-update) been included in any version of the Apache spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0, ieee

I am referring to below IEEE paper :

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7973685/authors#authors

Here by **PRDD** they mean **Partial-update RDD**.

I tried to search same but couldn't find any references in spark documentation.

Hence, asking here if it has been included in any of the version of the spark.

Answer (score 0):

It has not been included in any official Spark build.